# How to solve $\sum_{k=1}^{2500}\left \lfloor{\sqrt{k}}\right \rfloor $?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was trying to solve $\sum_{k=1}^{2500}\left \lfloor{\sqrt{k}}\right \rfloor $ using  Iverson's brackets but I can't get the bounds right. I think I'm also missing something.

Here's what I did:

$ m = \left \lfloor{\sqrt{k}}\right \rfloor$

$\sum_{m,k} \space m \space[ m = \left \lfloor{\sqrt{k}}\right \rfloor][0 \leq k < 2,500]$

$\sum_{m,k} \space m \space [ m^2 \leq k < (m+1)^2 ][0 \leq k \leq 2,500]$

$\sum_{m,k} \space m \space[ m^2 \leq k \leq 2,500 < (m+1)^2 ]$

from here I'm not sure what will be the bounds of $m$. I'm new to this kind of sum manipulation so please bear with me.

Comment: $m$ will be between $1$ and $50$.

Comment: But why can't I get the right result?

Comment: I think you really ought to write out the first, say, ten or twenty terms of the sum (terms, not partial sums) and see what they actually are, how many there are of each value.  Guess how the pattern continues, prove that that's the case, and then have a much easier time. Don't manipulate blindly without knowing where you're supposed to end up. That works in textbooks, but almost nothing is ever actually discovered that way.

Comment: Can you guys continue my solution?

Comment: @Math_Enthusiast You can probably easily continue it yourself after you've followed my hint, because then you know where the manipulation is supposed to take you, which makes it that much easier to move forwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have
$$\sum_{m=1}^{50}m\sum_k[m^2\le k<\min\left((m+1)^2,2501\right)].$$
The inner sum is just the number of $k$ for which the inequality holds.
For $m<50$ that number is just $(m+1)^2-m^2$, and for $m=50$ it's $1$. So
one gets
$$\sum_{m=1}^{49}m\left((m+1)^2-m^2\right)+50.$$

Comment: What does $min((m+1)^2,2501)$ mean?

Comment: $\min(a,b)$ is the *minimum* of $a$ and $b$, the smaller of the two (and either one when both are equal). Compare $\max(a,b)$.

Comment: I was looking for this solution thank you!!

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding this why does the inequality fail at m = 50? I'm sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: @Math_Enthusiast What's the question? Are you asking how many integers satisfy $2500\le k<2501$?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: You know that $\lfloor\sqrt{k}\rfloor = m$ if and only if $m^2 \le k \le (m+1)^2-1$. Hence:

$\lfloor\sqrt{k}\rfloor = 1$ for $1 \le k \le 3$ ($3$ values of $k$)

$\lfloor\sqrt{k}\rfloor = 2$ for $4 \le k \le 8$ ($5$ values of $k$)

$\lfloor\sqrt{k}\rfloor = 3$ for $9 \le k \le 15$ ($7$ values of $k$)

...

$\lfloor\sqrt{k}\rfloor = 49$ for $49^2 \le k \le 50^2-1 = 2499$ ($?$ values of $k$)

$\lfloor\sqrt{k}\rfloor = 50$ for $k = 2500 = 50^2$ ($1$ value of $k$)

Can you use this information to evaluate the sum?

Answer (score 1):

We have $\lfloor \sqrt{k}\rfloor=m\,\, m^2\le k<(m+1)^2$. Thus, $$\sum_{k=1}^{2500}\lfloor \sqrt{k}\rfloor$$$$=1+1+1_{3\, \text{times}}+2+\ldots+2_{5\,\text{times}}+\ldots+k+\ldots+k_{2k+1\,\text{times}}+49+49+\ldots+49_{99\,\text{times}}+50$$$$=\left[\sum_{k=1}^{49}k(2k+1)\right]+50$$$$=\left[\sum_{k=1}^{49}2k^2+k\right]+50$$$$=\frac{49(50)(99)}{3}+50$$$$=80850+50=80900.$$

Comment: you forgot to multiply 2 to 40425.

Comment: @Math_Enthusiast thanks. edited now